powershell function not working as expected
i'm writing a simple function that retrieves AD users with a OU and Filter preset using the following code:
$OU = "OU=Users,DC=internal,DC=contoso,DC=com"
$Filter = "Department -eq 'HR'"
$FilePath = "C:\Scripts\Output.log"
$Timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"

# Function description
function GetFilteredUsers {
    param (
        [string]$OU,
        [string]$Filter
    )

    $FilteredUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter $Filter -SearchBase $OU

    if ($FilteredUsers.Count -eq 0) {
        "$Timestamp : No users in $OU matching filter $Filter" | Out-File -FilePath $FilePath -Append
        }
    else {write-host 'Hooray!'}

}

GetFilteredUsers($OU,$Filter)

When i run the code i get the following error message:
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Filter'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again
.
At line:13 char:41
+     $FilteredUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter $Filter -SearchBase $OU
+                                         ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

The output file seems to indicate the OU and Filter variables are somehow stuck together:

2024-04-03 10:11 : No users in OU=Users,DC=internal,DC=contoso,DC=com
Department -eq 'HR' matching filter

At first i thought a variable named $Filter might not be allowed, but running the code without function (get-aduser -filter $Filter -searchbase $OU) works flawlessly. Changing the variable names also didn't do the trick. What am i missing here?

Did you try calling GetFilteredUsers -OU $OU -Filter $Filter

I did not, this has solved the problem. I feel so stupid mixing up python with powershell here. Thanks so much!

Also: you forgot to pass $FilePath and $Timestamp to the function: right now it knows it because they are in the same script(scope) but it will break if called from a different scope. Just add them to the parameters of the function(though I'd suggest to just replace $Timestamp with $(Get-date  -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm") in the string)

You should input variables to function though parameters

GetFilteredUsers -OU $OU -Filter $Filter 


